# Finding intensity/noise measurement of hysteresis loop

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, statistics, data-analysis, ferromagnetism

I'm hoping I could get some help from the experimentalists on some data analysis.

I have a number of hysteresis loops taken at different angles around extinction of a polarizer on a photodiode. I want to find the loop (and by proxy the angle) with the optimal signal/noise ratio but I'm not sure how to go about analyzing the hysteresis loops to get a number that reflects this ratio.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is what you are trying to do the same as fitting a curve (eg ellipse) according to some criterion (eg least sum of squared deviations)?

Comment: A flag suggests this question might fit better on [datascience.se], but a physicist's insight might be helpful as well.

Comment: The biggest problem right now is that this is a fairly specialized measurement and it isn't even clear to me what the data is, much less how it should related to the physics in question. Which is why it would be very out of place on [datascience.se]. I think that more detail of what is being measured and how is necessary before there is much chance that this will be answered. @Alexander Keep in mind that no one here knows what your experimental setup is, nor what instrument you are taking data with: you've got to give us something to work with.

Comment: Is this MOKE, magneto-optic Kerr effect?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the symmetry properties of hysteresis loops to separate half of the noise from the signal. Let's say your signal is $U$, which is proportional to the magnetization, and you apply a field $H$. Even in the presence of exchange bias there is a point $(H_0,U_0)$ with respect to which the signal is antisymmetric: $U(H_0-\Delta H)=2U_0-U(H_0+\Delta H)$. The point $(H_0,U_0)$ can be determined from the coercive fields and the saturation signals. Now determine the symmetric and the antisymmetric part of the hysteresis loop with respect to that point. Your noise level is the standard deviation of the symmetric part normalized to the maximum signal in the antisymmetric part.

Note that this "noise" also includes quadratic Kerr signals (assuming you are measuring Kerr loops). But normally, you don't want to have them in your signal as well.